# Finding substring that starts with ':' until the first space after the ':' character

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I want to find a substring that starts with `:` and ends with `"`, and then replace all occurrences with `dd/mm/yyyy`.

How is this possible using oracle `regexp_replace`?

For example, `to_date('13/09/2016',:"SYS_B_08")` should become `to_date('13/09/2016','dd/mm/yyyy')`.

Thank you. Best regards.

;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select regexp_replace('to_date(''13/09/2016'',:"SYS_B_08")', ':"[^"]*"', 
                                                '''dd/mm/yyyy''') as new_str from dual;


NEW_STR                          
----------------------------------
to_date('13/09/2016','dd/mm/yyyy')
```